# No Microsoft ID platform and OpenID Connect protocol login parameters

Tags: authentication, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, azure-ad-msal, outlook-web-addins

The client id parameter is not passed when logging in from an app add-in to outlook.

The default browser uses Microsoft edge and uses the Microsoft openid login function.

The code below is the msal code set in my angular app.

```
const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ') > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') > -1;
export var _msalConfig: Configuration = {
  auth: {
clientId: '', // This is your client ID
authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/', // This is your tenant ID
redirectUri: '', // This is your redirect URI
},
cache: {
  cacheLocation: "localStorage",
  storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE,
}
};

@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
],
  imports: [
BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
HttpClientModule,
FormsModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true }),
MsalModule.forRoot(_msalConfig, {
  popUp: !isIE,
  consentScopes: [
    'user.read',
    'openid',
    'profile',
  ],
  unprotectedResources: [],
  protectedResourceMap: [
    ['https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me', ['user.read']]
  ],
  extraQueryParameters: {}
})
],
})
```

If you log in from the web page, it works normally, but if you log in through the add-in app inside Outlook, the following error message appears.

error:invalid_request
error_description:The mandatory 'client_id' parameter is missing.

If anyone knows about the error, please help me.

Comment: Sounds like client-id is not passed correctly. I would suggest you to debug and see how the control flow works; also i would suggest you to use developer tools in IE/Edge. This way you can see whether the value is passed correctly or not.

Comment: In addition, i want you to check the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins

Comment: When using the SSO token as an identity in an Outlook add-in, we recommend that you also use the Exchange identity token as an alternate identity. Users of your add-in may use multiple clients, and some may not support providing an SSO token. By using the Exchange identity token as an alternate, you can avoid having to prompt these users for credentials multiple times. Here is the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/implement-sso-in-outlook-add-in

Comment: Does the above helped?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this we are facing similar problems would be interested to hear how it worked out

Answer (score 1):

- Sounds like client-id is not passed correctly. I would suggest you to debug and see how the control flow works; also i would suggest you to use developer tools in IE/Edge. This way you can see whether the value is passed correctly or not. In addition, i want you to check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins).
- When using the SSO token as an identity in an Outlook add-in, we recommend that you also use the Exchange identity token as an alternate identity. Users of your add-in may use multiple clients, and some may not support providing an SSO token. By using the Exchange identity token as an alternate, you can avoid having to prompt these users for credentials multiple times. Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/implement-sso-in-outlook-add-in).

Comment: When we add a manifest file for the user to load our application, the application is hosted on sharepoint. The first thing it does it try to hit sharepoint and gets an error like the one in the question when it fails on SSO for only some users.. I am wondering would the exchange token resolve this do you think and if so where would that code go, can it go into the manifest file or how would we implement the exchange token in place of SSO it s hard to understand that from the docs..